# Can't print with MacBook Air on a Wireless Printer

Tags: wifi, catalina, printing, error, smb

My printer is HP LaserJet M15A connected via USB to my router. Currently, I'm running on macOS Catalina version 10.15.13.
I can see and add the printer under "Printer & Scanners" - "Windows" - workgroup - fastgate - "HP_LaserJet-M14-M17_VNC3B87838". 
The add seems to be done correctly (using the correct driver), but when trying to print I see "Unable to connect to printer".
My router is Technicolor MediaAccess DGA4131FWB. I tried many stuff to fix the problem, but nothing works:

Added the following lines to my nsmb.conf

`[default]
port445=both
smb_neg=smb1_only
signing_required=no`

Tried to set manually the ip of the router (192.168.1.254) and ports (80,139,445,631 and all the other opened ports) from CUPS but no result. The output of `nmap 192.168.1.254` is:

`PORT      STATE    SERVICE
53/tcp    open     domain
80/tcp    open     http
139/tcp   open     netbios-ssn
443/tcp   filtered https
445/tcp   open     microsoft-ds
631/tcp   open     ipp
5000/tcp  open     upnp
8080/tcp  open     http-proxy
8888/tcp  open     sun-answerbook
49152/tcp open     unknown`

I can also print correctly from my Desktop PC with Windows 10, and from my Android smartphone using PrinterShare. But not on Mac.

Anyone have any idea what's wrong?
Thank you